# Merge Multiple CSV Files

Tags: php, csv

I am Trying to Merge Multiple CSV Files but unable to do that.
Please have a look my code I dont know whats wrong with my code.
**csvfiles** is a directory which contains multiple same format Files.

[Download Sample CSV Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByLvmlWPf_NRZXNlMWlpYVVFdDQ)

**My Code**

```
$csvdir = "./csvfiles/";
$result = fopen('./csvfiles/merge.csv', 'w');
$test="";
if (is_dir($csvdir)) {
    if ($handle = opendir($csvdir)){
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
            if (substr($file, -4) === ".csv") {
                $csvcontent = file_get_contents($file);
                fwrite($result, $csvcontent);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
fclose($result);
```

Comment: Which error do you face when you execute the code?

Comment: No Error, logically it should merge files, but new merge.csv files created with blank data

Comment: That means any of your `if(...)` condition is giving a `false` result.

Comment: every condition working file, i already checked

Comment: can you please tell what this says puting after file_get_contents ? echo "HERE" . "<" . $result . ">" . substr($csvcontent, 0,10) ;

Comment: $result returns blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

- At some point `opendir($csvdir)` will also include your `merge.csv` file. You want to avoid that. Keep it seperate.
- Keep file operations at minimum. For every .csv file in your loop you write to your `merge.csv`. Instead, collect the data to write in your loop and write only once.
- You're getting the wrong file contents in `file_get_contents($file);`. `$file` will only contain the filename, not the complete path.
- `$test` is never used.

Here's working code:

```
<?php

$csvdir = "./csvfiles/";
$csvcontent = '';
if (is_dir($csvdir)) {
    if ($handle = opendir($csvdir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
            if (substr($file, -4) === ".csv") {
                $csvcontent .= file_get_contents($csvdir . $file);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}

$result = fopen('./merge.csv', 'w');
fwrite($result, $csvcontent);
fclose($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code indeed merges my 10 CSV files, each file has 2 columns. I expect an output file with two columns, instead, output has 20 rows; the reason is below code places each csv file to 2 new columns. Image is also given [image]:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("/home/csv/")
 extension = 'csv'
 all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
 combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
 combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv4.csv")
 print('merging done')
```

Comment: how to save in two columns?